# Guardar varios DataFrames con un bucle for en diferentes hojas de un mismo archivo excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

Les agradecería su ayuda, tengo el siguiente código:

```
for embalse in ["PIL", "PUL", "VDV"]:
    vo = pd.read_csv('...\\Desktop\\pucv.xlsx',encoding='utf-8')
    vo=vo[vo["Embalse"]==embalse]
    writer = ExcelWriter('...\\Desktop\\embalses.xlsx')
    vo.to_excel(writer, embalse, index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es rescatando datos de una columna cuyo nombre es variable y dependerá del recorrido del `for`, cada vez que termine el bucle, se guarde en un Excel y al pasar nuevamente con el bucle abrir el archivo creado anteriormente y solo adicionarle el nombre variable "embalse".

El problema es que funciona pero se sobre escribe el archivo, y finalmente resulta un archivo Excel con solo una hoja cuyo nombre es el ultimo, "VDV".

¿Cómo podría lograr que no se sobrescriba y solo agregue una nueva hoja, con el objetivo de terminar con un archivo de Excel con tantas hojas como bucles en `for` haya realizado?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que abres el archivo de destino y llamas a `save` en cada iteración. Vamos a ir por partes:

- No debes abrir el archivo de origen en cada iteración, eso es ineficiente e innecesario. Crea el DataFrame fuera del ciclo y en cada iteración simplemente filtra usando la columna y usa la vista generada para generar la hoja mediante el método `to_excel` de la misma.
- Igualmente, abre el archivo de destino una sola vez fuera del `for`.
- Por último, solo debes llamar al método `save` una sola vez cuando tengas completo el contenido del Excel, es decir, cuando termine el ciclo. No obstante es mejor que uses el estamento `with` y que se encarge automáticamente de guardar y cerrar el archivo al terminar.

El código quedaría algo así:

```
import pandas as pd


vo = pd.read_csv('.../Desktop/pucv.csv', encoding='utf-8')
with pd.ExcelWriter('.../Desktop/embalses.xlsx') as writer:
    for embalse in ["PIL", "PUL", "VDV"]:    
        emb_rows = vo[vo.Embalse == embalse]
        emb_rows.to_excel(writer, embalse, index=False)
```

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias probaré dicha opción y comento.